# Using lambdas as asynchronous callbacks

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a program, where I cannot use the standard `std::async` and threading mechanisms. Instead I have to code the program like so:

```
void processor( int argument, std::function<void(int)> callback ) {
  int blub = 0;

  std::shared_ptr<object> objptr = getObject();

  // Function is called later.
  // All the internal references are bound here!
  auto func = [=, &blub]() {
    // !This will fail since blub is accessed by reference!
    blub *= 2;

    // Since objptr is copied by value it works.
    // objptr holds the value of getObject().
    objptr->addSomething(blub);

    // Finally we need to call another callback to return a value
    callback(blub);
  };

  objptr = getAnotherObject();

  // Puts func onto a queue and returns immediately.
  // func is executed later.
  startProcessing(func);
}
```

I now would like to know whether I am doing it right or what the best way of using lambdas as asynchronous callbacks is.

EDIT: Added expected behavior to the code comments.
See answer/comments for possible solutions for the problem with `blub`.

Comment: That's kind of vague. It's kind of hard to answer questions like "what is the best way of doing X". You can use lambdas as callbacks. What else do you need to know?

Comment: `blub` is gone, and the reference to it shouldn't be valid when labda is executed, right?

Comment: Basically it would be interesting, how asynchronity works with object lifetimes and scoping. All the info I read was by using lambdas synchronous - cannot find anything on asynchronous.

Comment: There's no magic. The usual scoping and lifetime rules apply, and it is *your* responsibility to make sure that when you hand out a reference, the object remains alive long enough.

Comment: @VJovic I would assume as much - but is objptr there?

Comment: I don't think so. I think it is gone as well

Comment: As @KerrekSB said, there is no magic. The lambda is really just a function object. It doesn't magically add a garbage collector to the language, or alter the rules of object lifetimes. Objects captured by value in the lambda exist as copies *in* the lambda functor. Objects captured by reference exist as references stored in the lambda functor. And then it's your responsibility to ensure that the object they point to stays valid

Comment: This sort of thing tends to come from unqualified advice about using RAII and always allocating stuff on the stack - the sort of thing that is spectacularly disastrous with multithreaded apps.  This: 'On the contrary, you should always prefer stack allocations, to the extent that as a rule of thumb, you should never have new/delete in your user code' is the first line of an answer on SO that got 44 points with lots of plaudit comments from developers who had obviously never written a single multithreaded app or setup a single asynchronous callback, (same thing, really).

Comment: @VJovic objptr is still there. Everything except blub is copied by value. So `objptr` in the function object will simply be a copy of the original `objptr` and hold a valid pointer (which is the purpose of a `shared_ptr`).

Comment: @MartinJames: care to link to that answer? I almost never see people arguing against dynamic allocation, only against naked pointers and new, and in favor of managed pointers and things like `std::make_shared`, which makes sense, certainly from a threading perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function object will contain a reference to the local variable `blub`. *As in every other situation* in the language, this won't make the local variable live after the function ends.

Copies of all the other captured objects will be stored within the function object, since they're captured-by-value. This means there's no issue with them.

If you want it to live after the function ends, you cannot tie its lifetime to the function: you need *dynamic storage duration*. A `std::unique_ptr` can be used to to handle the cleanup of such an object, but it gets a bit annoying because you can't "capture-by-move" into a lambda :S

```
auto blub = make_unique<int>(0); // [1]

std::shared_ptr<object> objptr = getObject();

// use std::bind to store the unique_ptr with the lambda
auto func = std::bind([=](std::unique_ptr<int>& blub) {
  *blub *= 2;

  objptr->addSomething(*blub);

  callback(*blub);
}, std::move(blub)); // move the unique_ptr into the function object

objptr = getAnotherObject();

// func is not copiable because it holds a unique_ptr
startProcessing(std::move(func)); // move it
```

As an added note, the old deprecated `std::auto_ptr` would actually work fine here, because if the lambda captures it by value it gets copied and its strange copy semantics are exactly what's needed.

---

<sub>1. See [GOTW #102](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/) for `make_unique`.</sub>

Comment: Which seems to me should end in the rule that you should always access stuff outside the lambda by using `std::shared_ptr` and passing them by value. Which would then erase the need for the `std::bind` call. Using `std::bind` would IMO make sense if you indeed have blub as an object and then want to move it into the lambda.

Comment: @LCIDFire yes, that sounds like a nice rule. I used bind here because `blub` being a local variable it isn't likely to be shared.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Nice to pass unique_ptr like that. It's lifetime bound to the lifetime of lambda basically, even though is passed by ref as lambda argument(there would be no other way of course).